# Problems installing SQL Server 2008 SP2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I installed a 90 day Eval version of SQL Server 2008 SP2 downloaded from Microsoft. I ran ths installation and it all went thru without any errors. Then i opened the Configuration menu to see if the server needs to be started. There were no entries in the server list. So i unistalled all the SQL Server items. I again ran the 'SQLServer2008SP2-KB2285068-x86-ENU.exe' file. It again gave me the Landing page. I clicked on Install new instance. It now asks me for installation media folder. Apparently the EXE extracts into some temporary folder which is deleted as soon as the Landing page is created. So i dont have a installation media folder to point to.

Any idea how i can overcome this ?

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to download the file again, and run this command:
"SQLServer2008SP2-KB2285068-x86-ENU.exe /x:c:\SQLServer2008Install" (minus the quotes). This will extract it to the c:\SQLServer2008Install folder, or pick the folder of your choice. You can then point to that extracted location for any future use.

Just as a note: Many Microsoft programs can be extracted with the /x switch. Just run the executable with /? at the end and see what the switches are supported. This file is an exception in that the /? does not show the /x switch as an option, but I downloaded the 64-bit version of that file, and it did extract as I showed above to the location specified.

Answer (score 0):

Read what id in installation log file:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\ (last folder ordered by date)\ summary.* file.

There should be information what was during installation session. All errors will be described here.