# How to completely un-install SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I had installed SQL Server 2008 SP2 Eval and got into some problems. Another post in this forum helped me to retry installation - [Problems installing SQL Server 2008 SP2](https://serverfault.com/questions/275110/problems-installing-sql-server-2008-sp2)

However when i rerun installation it just loops back with no results. Is there one batch of commands which will make the PC just forget it ever had SQL Server in it, remove all registry, folders, and traces whatsoever,  and allow me to do a fresh install ?

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manually unstalling SQL: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955404

Answer (score 2):

After uninstall use something like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to get rid of registry problems.

Also make sure your not choosing an option on uninstall to save settings.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, there isn't a tool specific to removing a hosed SQL server installation.

The main problem you are seeing that is causing the install loop, is that reg and directory entries still exist.

Best way, is to uninstall all the components that it will let you from Add/Remove Programs. Then, physically delete the SQL server directories and registry entries.

There was [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301)  tool back in the day for automatically removing Office and other MS products that worked fantastically on just about anything else on a machine, but is no longer supported. If you do a search for the .exe file, it exists all over the place.

From personal experience, and dealing with all flavors of SQL on a daily basis, I would recommend seeking out the tool if you find items in Add/Remove Programs that will not come out.